editing files in batches from a huge amount of data
I ran into an issue:
I have folders with usually 50-150 text files, which I need to modify. 
sed is not an option, since the changes cannot be automated
(sometimes "ss" need to be changed, sometimes not). 
Most of the necessary changes were already made with SED. 
I COULD use vi * in the folder and go through each file
and then save it or open each one individually,
but this would make the brain sick.
I would like to open 5 files in a row, and when they are done,
next time I have a free brain open the next 5 files and so on. 
Any smart ideas? 
Unfortunately,
the file naming convention don't offer "smart" chunks to modify.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I like Stéphane's approach, but would say that this calls for a bit of text versioning tooling, anyways; no need to build this ourselves, and we get bonus functionality if we use the right tools, like the ability to check our changes and go back to the unchanged version.
So here's what I'd do:
Preparation

Initialize  a git index: cd yourfiles/ ; git init .
Let's have all the files in their original state the git: git add * followed by git commit -m "Files in original state" (we can later compare to this!). Let's tag this with the tag name "original": git tag original
Tell git that, nah, we'll not track these files right now (we'll add them back later as we work through them): git rm --cached * (which removes them from the index, but not from the directory you're working in) followed by git commit -m "clean slate".

Great. So that's our preparation. Now, when you have a free head:
Take the first five of the currently untracked files, process them
# in zsh
files=( ${(0)"$(git ls-files --other -z | head -z -n 5)"} )
vim -- $files
git add -- $files

# in bash:
readarray -td '' -n 5 files < <(git ls-files --other -z)
vim -- "${files[@]}"
git add -- "${files[@]}"

#in both:
git commit -m 'done some work'

(please do feel encouraged to write a better message than "done some work", if there's anything important to write regarding these files)
You can always check the files that you haven't worked on yet with git ls-files --other (or git status). You can compare your changes with the original, unmodified files, using git diff original -- FILENAMES. You can also compare all the changes you've already done and already committed: git diff original HEAD.

oh neat I didn't figure out the zero-byte splitting syntax for zsh, and didn't know bash could handle that at all!

@StéphaneChazelas fixed my answer, thanks!

Ah, man zshexpn: Split the result of the expansion on null bytes.  This is a shorthand for `ps:\0:'. OK, that is one place in that man page I didn't look

I'd use info rather than man as zsh manual is more of the size of a book than a page. The index is pretty good in zsh's info manual. See info zsh flags for instance here.

If using zsh and vim.
The first time:
todo=( *(.) ); typeset -p todo > .todo

The next times:
source ./.todo

Then edit 5 at a time with:
vim -- $todo[1,5]

Within vim: :argdo %s/ss/something-else/gc for global replace with prompt for each substitution.
When done with those five, remove from the $todo list and save that list for later:
todo[1,5]=(); typeset -p todo > .todo

Alternatively, move the files that have been processed in a done directory (still with zsh):
mkdir -p done
vim -- *(.[1,5])
mv -- *(.[1,5]) done/

Or with an anonymous function to pass those first 5 regular files to both vim and mv:  () { vim $@ && mv $@ done; } ./*(.[1,5])
With ./*(.[1,5]), you get the first 5 non-hidden regular files in lexical order. Change to ./*(.OL[1,5]) for the 5 biggest ones or ./*(.Om[1,5]) for the 5 oldest ones.

This is a not-very-technical question — i.e.,
there’s an obvious technical answer (vi *),
and you have a non-technical issue with it. 
So this calls for a not-very-technical answer:
Open a new window. 
Run vi * in that window. 
Edit files until your brain gets tired. 
Then minimize that window. 
When you’re ready to go back to work, go back to that window.
If, by chance, you don’t have access to windows,
Run vi *. 
Edit files until your brain gets tired. 
Then suspend that vi process with :suspend. 
When you’re ready to go back to work,
go back to that process with the fg command.

If you're using Vim and not original vi or some other derivative, you could do it using Vim itself:
vim *

Then:

Open the first 5 files in tabs:
:1,5bdo tabe

(This will open an extra empty tab, you can just close it.)

When you're done with these 5 tabs (editing, saving, etc.), delete their corresponding buffers:
:1,5bd


Go to (1).



If the things you are interested in can be grepped for (even if you can't script their replacements), consider using the quickfix list. For example, if you're interested in all mentions of ss in some/dir, then open Vim and then do:
:grep -R ss some/dir

This will populate Vim's quickfix list with all files that grep listed, and open the first one in the current window. Then use :cw to open the quickfix list in a new window, and you can press Enter on each item to open it in the other window.
 (I used Ctrl-W H to move the quickfix window to the side, here - by default you get a horizontal split with the quickfix window at the bottom.)
(Or you can also open the first 5 files in tabs using 1,5cfdo, but there's no convenient way to remove items from the list, so this is not repeatable.)
